# Убрать блок при клике

Tags: html, jquery, css

Нужно чтобы по нажатию на "cat1" появлялся блок "subcat", а блок "cat" либо исчезал, либо "subcat" перекрывал его

```js
$('.cat li').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).children('.subcat').show();
})
```

```css
.cat {
  list-style:none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.subcat {
  display: none;
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  background: violet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cat">
  <li>cat1
    <ul class="subcat">
      <li>subcat2</li>
      <li>subcat2</li>
      <li>subcat2</li>
      <li>subcat2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>cat1</li>
  <li>cat1</li>
  <li>cat1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо скрывать не весь li, а только текст внутри:

```js
$('.cat li').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.content').hide();
  $(this).children('.subcat').show();
})
```

```css
.cat {
  list-style:none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.subcat {
  display: none;
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  background: violet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cat">
  <li>
    <span class="content">cat1</span>
    <ul class="subcat">
      <li>subcat2</li>
      <li>subcat2</li>
      <li>subcat2</li>
      <li>subcat2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="content">cat1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="content">cat1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="content">cat1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас не понятно что такое cat1, неправильна создана html структура (li не закрыто где надо) и  вы ищите при помощи jquery соседа, а надо потомка (.children() )  Но основная проблема в неправильном html

Comment: внёс правки. всё равно не понятно пока как сделать. 
Кликаем на элемент списка, но нужно спрятать сам блок cat. В таком случае тогда ничего не будет отображаться. Верно ли будет просто при клике спозиционировать блок subcat поверх cat?